# Anonymous Action classes cause IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, struts2, junit, jmock

I have some anonymous `Action` classes in unit test code. Anonymous classes have no name. `Class#getSimpleName` returns `""`. It causes `IndexOutOfBoundException` when initialing convention-plugin.
`PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder#buildConfiguration` skips all interfaces, enums, annotations, and abstract classes. It should skip anonymous classes too. Add `actionClass.isAnonymous()` to the skip condition.
I have some anonymous Action classs in my unit test code. It's not good design.

```
private PageAction action;

@Before 
public void beforeEach() {
    action = new PageAction() {};
}
@Test 
public void shouldAcceptAndPublicPageId() { 
    action.setPageId(1); 
    assertEquals(1, action.getRequestedPageId()); 
}
...
// To bypass complex logic in ViewPageAction
@Before 
public void beforeEach() {
    action = new ViewPageAction() {
        boolean isPageBookmarkedByUser(Page page, User user) { return true; }
        VisitPage visitPage() { return null; }
    };
    coreService = mockery.mock(CoreService.class);
    action.setCoreService(coreService);
    uiService = mockery.mock(UiService.class);
    action.setUiService(uiService);
    pageRepository = mockery.mock(PageRepository.class);
    action.setPageRepository(pageRepository);
    pageAttachmentRepository = mockery.mock(PageAttachmentRepository.class);
    action.setPageAttachmentRepository(pageAttachmentRepository);
    wiki = WikiTest.publicWiki();
    action.setWiki(wiki);
    User user = UserTest.FOO;
    action.setUser(user);
}
@Test 
public void success() {
    final Page page = PageTest.FOO_PAGE;
    final String text = "Content of the page";
    final PageRevision latestRevision = MockPageRevision.FOO_REV2;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this isn't a very clear question, so this is a guess:

Have you tried making your anonymous ViewPageAction into a proper class?

```
// somewhere in your test class...
private static class DummyViewPageAction extends ViewPageAction {
    boolean isPageBookmarkedByUser(Page page, User user) { return true; }
    VisitPage visitPage() { return null; }
}

// start of your @Before method...
@Before
public void beforeEach() {
    action = new DummyViewPageAction();
    ...
```